# putting button in navigationItem.titleView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wanted to put a timer in the title label of a tableViewController. To my surprise, storyboard let me drop a button the title and I got everything working, however, I need to button to differentiate between single and double taps. Single tap starts and stops the timer, and double tap would reset it back to zero. In order to make a button recognize both type of taps, I had to create a subclass of UIButton, which means that I am now adding the button programmatically rather than through storyboard. In viewDidLoad, I tried to add the button to the titleView of the navigationItem but nothing's showing when I run it in the simulator. I set the x,y coordinates like this

```
self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds.size.width/2
```

thinking it would place the button in the middle.

I'm not sure if I've messed up the coordinates or done something else wrong, but nothing's showing. Can you suggest how it might be done?

```
    MMTimerButton *button = [MMTimerButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];  
    [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds.size.width/2, self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds.size.height/2, 160.00, 40.0);  
    [self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: You can still add a custom button in the storyboard. Just drag in a UIButton, set its type to custom, then change its class to your subclass. The reason your code doesn't work is that the title view is nil unless you create one.

Comment: @rdelmar yes, forgot about that thanks,

Comment: You are repeating the same mistake you make in this question of yours (which is almost the same question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691867/can-a-titleview-be-made-to-accept-tap-gestures

Comment: @matt same mistake but different question