# can a titleView be made to accept tap gestures?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a custom class MMTimerButton, I set up the button to respond to a single and a double tap

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        singleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
        singleTapRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded=YES;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
        doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired=2;

        [singleTapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail: doubleTapRecognizer];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTapRecognizer];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I implement the two methods like this in the same file

```
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    NSLog(@"single tap");
}
-(void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    NSLog(@"double tap");
}
```

In the header, I declare two methods

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MMTimerButton : UIButton
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
-(void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
```

In the storyboard, I added a button to the interface and set its custom class to be MMTimerButton.

Nothing's happening when I click the button (in the simulator). One click, two click, both nothing.

I also tried doing it without a button, just adding gesture recognizers to the titleView. Nothing happens when I click on the title in the simulator

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer* doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget : self action : @selector (handleDoubleTap:)];   
UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget : self action : @selector (handleSingleTap:)];
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail : doubleTap];
[doubleTap setDelaysTouchesBegan : YES];
[singleTap setDelaysTouchesBegan : YES];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired : 2];
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired : 1];
self.navigationItem.title =@"title";
[self.navigationItem.titleView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[self.navigationItem.titleView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

However, when I add this code to header view, it works fine (in the simulator)

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    headerLabel.tag = section;
    headerLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0:00",section];
    headerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    headerLabel.frame=CGRectMake(10,-5,tableView.frame.size.width,41);

    UITapGestureRecognizer* doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget : self action : @selector (handleDoubleTap:)];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget : self action : @selector (handleSingleTap:)];
    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail : doubleTap];
    [doubleTap setDelaysTouchesBegan : YES];
    [singleTap setDelaysTouchesBegan : YES];
    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired : 2];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired : 1];
    self.navigationItem.title =@"title";
    [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    return headerLabel;

    //return nil;
}
```

Comment: I have a custom view class used for a navigation bar's `titleView` and it responds to double-taps just fine so I know it works in general. Try getting your custom view to work with just one tap gesture first. Also just use a custom `UIView` and not a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing a lot of troubled code here, so it's hard to know where to start.

- In the case of your `initWithFrame:`, the problem is that this method is never called for a button. Moreover, you've got a conflict because the button already contains the ability to respond to a tap, internally (it's a button!).
- In the second set of code, you never set the `titleView` to a view, so it is nil, and your code does nothing. Also, you can't set both the `title` and the `titleView` (you are setting the `title`).

The answer to your title question is, of course a `titleView` can respond to a tap. Lots of apps do this (including mine).

Also, you do not need your `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` - a single tap gesture recognizer and a double tap gesture recognizer already know how to mediate between themselves.

So basically my advice would be: stop over-complicating everything. Don't make big assumptions and dive in. Start with stuff that you know works and take little steps. Test everything with logging / breakpoints as you go, to see that what's happening is what you imagine.